# Suggestion more then question about tezos course on plural sight

Tags: smart-contracts, baking, smartpy, michelson, blockchain

There is a good course about BlockChain fundamentals on Plural sight but addressing ethereum. It could be great if someone can create similar curse there with targeting tezos with